# Best way to make a variable declared in a method visible in an inner function declaration, in Python?

Tags: python, scope, attributes

I have a *method* which includes: variable declaration, inner functions declarations. I want the variable to be available in the inner functions. All is in a class. All belongs to a code generator, then I can modify only the *method* content, not the class.

Here are my attempts:

```
class SomeClassICannotModify(AbstractConditional):
     def __init__(self, a, b):
         .....
 
     def method_which_content_I_can_modify(self):
         myvar = 1  
 
         def my_inner_func():
             global myvar
             myvar = 1
             return myvar

        print(my_inner_func()
```

Of course, this leads to an error: `NameError: name 'myvar' is not defined` since `global` refers to variables declared at module level.

Next attempt without the misused `global`:

```
     def method_which_content_I_can_modify(self):
         myvar = 1  
 
         def my_inner_func():
             myvar = 1
             return myvar
```

Here I get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cond' referenced before assignment`. `cond` is to be understood after code generation that adds stuff, so read `myvar` instead.

If I try to pass `myvar` as an argument like here:

```
     def method_which_content_I_can_modify(self):
         myvar = 1  
 
         def my_inner_func(v = myvar):
             v = 1
             return v
```

I get the same error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cond' referenced before assignment`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution I could find is as follows:

```
 def method_which_content_I_can_modify(self):
     myvar = 1  

     def my_inner_func(v = myvar):
         v = 1
         return v
```

This is the last trial I made in the question, the error was for another reason.